# Ionic http request fails in YII2

Tags: ionic-framework, yii2, cors

I have a problem with sending HTTP request to the backend that is on YII2. My Ionic code looks like this:

```
let headers = new Headers(); 
    headers.append('content-type','application/json');
    headers.append('token', this.sessiontoken);
    let options  = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers}); 
    console.log('HEADERS-----------', options);
    return this.http.get(this.userprofileapi,options) 
                        .map((res:Response) => res.json()) 
                        .catch((error:any)=>Observable.of(error))
```

And in YII2 I turned on my cors filters:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        'cors' => [
            // restrict access to
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => ['*'],
            'Origin'                           => ["*"],
            'Access-Control-Request-Method'    => ['POST', 'GET'],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
            'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600
        ],
    ];

    return $behaviors ;
}
```

But in sending its giving the error :

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

And not sending the headers. Is some one faced with this issue before? And how i can fix that?

Comment: Still actual :)

Comment: you dont need this line `Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => ['*'],` and try adding domain names into `Origin` rather than `*` , change it with `['http://localhost:8100']`

Comment: Ive tried that, it doent help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this site](https://blog.ionicframework.com/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) explains quite well what is going on.

set up your `ionic.project` file to be something like:

```
{
  "name": "proxy-example",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://cors.api.com/api"
    }
  ]
}
```

Run your server with `ionic serve`.
As we specified above, when you access the ionic server at the path `http://localhost:8100/api`, it will proxy requests out to `http://cors.api.com/api` on your behalf.
Thus, no CORS is required.